# pyserial write and read data RS232

Tags: python, pyserial

I have a cable with RS232 serial port and I connect the heads to my pc by USB serial adaptor.
I want to send a data from one comport and receive the data from another comport.
but I have problem with encoding. I can send the data (I can see data in Hterm terminal) but when I want to read data from python it shows empty message.

```
import serial
import serial.tools
import serial.tools.list_ports
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
root.resizable(False, False)

def myClick():
     scm = SerialConnectionManager('COM6', 38400)
     scm.connect_port()
     scm.send_data('hellodd ')
     scm.disconnect_port()
     serialObj = serial.Serial('COM5', 38400, timeout=0.5)
     receivedData = serialObj.readline()
     print(receivedData)
     serialObj.close()


# myLabel = Label(root, text="Hello eeWorld")
# myLabel.pack()
firstButton = Button(root, text="Init Data Rate", command=myClick )
firstButton.pack()

class SerialConnectionManager():
    def __init__(self, port, baudrate):
        self.sc = serial.Serial()
        self.sc.baudrate = baudrate
        self.sc.port = port


    def connect_port(self):
        if (not self.sc.is_open):
            self.sc.open()

    def disconnect_port(self):
        if (self.sc.is_open):
            self.sc.close()

    def send_data(self, message):
        if (self.sc.is_open and message != ""):
            self.sc.write(message.encode())

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You open the port, send data, then close it _then_ open the other port and try to read. Opening/closing may clear the io buffers. Try opening both ports. Then send and receive. Then close both ports.

Comment: Side note: `readline()` expects the incoming message to end with `'\n'`. If it doesn't find a newline it will timeout - if a timeout is provided (which you have done).

Comment: …and you never send the `'\n'` that `readine()` waits for. Try `scm.send_data('hellodd \n')`